# How to remove all Custom option of all Products in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to remove all custom option from all magento products. I have about 4k products. and all has custom option. now we don't need custom option. so we need to need to remove all. Is the any simple solution as if I can remove all custom option easily

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Preferably don't directly execute a database query, but use magento models:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::init();

Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getCollection()->walk('delete');
```

This -will- use multiple queries to delete your product options, but it should not be a big issue for 4000 products.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to remove all custom options from all products at once, then you can execute the following SQL query in your database:

```
delete from catalog_product_option
```

But be sure to backup your database first. Did you mean something like that.